# Muffler recently replaced and is already cracked

Tags: chevrolet, muffler, cavalier, cracking

I have a 05 cavalier with a replaced muffler and it’s already cracked after a month of driving I do drive a lot so maybe that’s why but it always drips water too

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it's already cracked, seems this might be a warranty type question?

Comment: Can you post a photo?  I find it highly unusual that a new muffler from a reputable shop "cracked" even if it had water dripping on it.  Remember that these things are designed so that you can drive in the rain, so a bit of dripping water should not present a problem.